# Getting 415 Error When Sending JSON and Multipartfile Together From Angular To Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

My backend REST method works fine when I test it in Postman, but when I try to pass the arguments from the frontend I get a 415 "Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported." error.

Here is my backend method:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping
    @Operation(summary = "Publish a new message", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "apiKey"))
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> create (
        @Valid @RequestPart MessageInquiryDto messageDto,
        @RequestPart MultipartFile file
    ) {
        LOGGER.info("POST /api/v1/messages body: {}", messageDto);
        messageMapper.messageToDetailedMessageDto(
            messageService.publishMessage(file, messageMapper.messageInquiryDtoToMessage(messageDto)));
        String message;
        try {
            storageService.save(file);

            message = "Uploaded file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "Did not upload file, but saved url to message: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + ". Error: " + e.getMessage();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
        }
}
```

This is the create method in the Angular service layer:

```
createMessageService(message: Message, image: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('messageDto', JSON.stringify(message));
    formData.append('file', image);
    formData.forEach(file => console.log('File: ', file));

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.messageBaseUri, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      // headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Accept', 'multipart/form-data'),
      responseType: 'json'
    });

    return this.httpClient.request(req);
}
```

I tried making it accept multipart/form-data, but then I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

This would be my logic in the news component:

```
private createMessage(message: Message) {
    if (this.selectedFiles) {
      console.log(this.selectedFiles.item(0));
      const file: File | null = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
      console.log('file:');
      console.log(file);

      if (file) {
        this.currentFile = file;
        this.messageService.createMessageService(this.currentMessage, this.currentFile).subscribe({
          next: (event: any) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              // this.message = event.body.message;
              this.fileInfos = this.messageService.getFiles();
            }
          },
          error: (err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.currentFile = undefined;
          }
        });
     }
     this.selectedFiles = undefined;
    }
}

selectFile(event: any): void {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
}
```

```
<div class="form-group d-flex flex-column" *ngIf="!currentMessage.id">
            <label class="form-label">Upload Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="inputImage" accept="image/*"
                   (change)="selectFile($event)">
</div>

<button type="button" (click)="addMessage(messageForm); messageForm.valid && modal.dismiss('add message')" id="add-msg" class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="!currentMessage.id">Add message</button>
```

I hope you get the HTML code out of context, it shouldn't be a Problem.
Any help would be appreciated.